# Change part of a div seperatly

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change a part of a div which would be my logo, but it's part of a div that has a background to it. I need the Logo's background to be transparent but I cant see the change because it's part of a div called "four columns". Here is the code:

```
<div class="four columns">
    <h1 id="logo">Unlighted Gaming  <a href="http://unlightedgaming.com"><img id="logo_img" src="http://unlightedgaming.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Menulogo1.png" width="294" height="108" alt="Unlighted Gaming"></a></h1>
</div>
        <!--end logo-->
```

I tried to change it in css like this:

```
.four.columns.logo {
background: #transparent;
```

But no luck

Am I not suppose to use CSS?

Comment: `.four.columns .logo {opacity: 0;}`

Comment: not sure if this is the problem or not, but that should be `background: transparent`.  (drop the `#`)

Comment: also, in your selector, there should be a space between `.columns` and `.logo`: `.four.columns .logo`

Comment: No the # doesnt change anything

Comment: There are few error on your HTML markup and in CSS as well. check the DEMO. http://jsbin.com/xukivago/1/edit

Comment: .four.columns .logo {opacity: 0;} Didnt work

Comment: I know that's intentional by wordpress

Comment: on your wesbite the logo is not appear because the logo text color and background color is same.

Comment: Sorry, I think it's actually that your selector is off. For id you need to use `#`. So it would be: `.four.columns #logo {
background: transparent;`

Comment: Tried that already it has no effect

Answer (score 0):

You are using logo as id, but in your CSS you have referred as a class. Change your CSS like below.

```
.four.columns #logo {opacity: 0;} /* If you want to hide the element */

.four.columns #logo {background:transparent;} /* If you want to give transparent background*/
```

If you want to remove the black color you should write your code like below.

```
.four.column
{
  background:transparent !important; /* I use important because you want to overwrite the original code*/
}
```

Comment: This seems to work but in the wrong way, I'm not trying change the literal logo to transparent, I'm trying to remove the black around it

Comment: you have applied background:#000 to .four.columns in your css. Remove it and it will work.

Comment: I didn't mention this but there are other parts of "four columns" div that affect the whole site so changing the css would make the whole site look weird

Comment: i updated my answer. use like that it will not affect any other place.

Comment: you have applied a image on  class `.four.column` which is the root cause.  try to use this line.

`background:transparent  url("http://unlightedgaming.com/wp-content/themes/sweetdate/assets/images/patterns/black_pattern.gif") repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)`

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai why using un-necessary `!important` in code?

Comment: it looks like he want to overwrite from other css file.

Answer (score -1):

Best way to do it is add a new class to div `<div class="four columns">` e.g. `.logo-background`

`<div class="four columns logo-background">`

and add this CSS

```
.logo-background{
   background: transparent !important;
}
```

Comment: How do I add a new class?

Comment: But OP doesn't want to change the opacity of the `<div>`, he wants to change the opacity of the contained `<h1>`, which already has a unique id

Comment: Changing opacity won't work mate. The background is on it's parent div. Not on Logo <h1>..

Comment: Sorry, I meant transparency. Was going off his original selector in terms of what he wanted to edit.